# Sql Data Sync fails and no logs are available

Tags: azure, azure-data-sync

I have 2 SQL data sync groups setup

1. First one does a 1 way sync from azure to local db. Sync's only 1 table.
2. Second one does a 1 way sync from local db to the azure. Syncs 2 tables.

After setting it up and getting a few sync errors I was able to figure out what's wrong by checking the logs and fixing the problems. It was all running fine for a while and now it broke down.

[image]

I got a sync error every time sync is attempted - however this time I'm not able to fix anything because I don't have any visibility on what's wrong - when I click on the Log tab in the Azure Management portal it just stays blank - no details come up.

I click [Logs]
Wait spinner comes up
[image]

And then it looks like this:
[image]

Another detail worth mentioning is that the error only occurs for the Second sync group that I have.

Here's what I've attempted so far

1. I poked around the azure management portal to try to find another way of looking at the logs - looking for something like ftp access to the log file - couldn't find anything like that.
2. I refreshed schema in the sync rules tab.
3. Used the SQL Data Sync agent tool on the premise to do the ping operation. Restarted the sql data sync windows service.
4. Made sure I have the latest SQL Data Sync Agent installed.

I'm wondering what are my options from here...

I'm close to trying to deleting and recreating the sync group... I'm not too comfortable doing this because I know there are some sql tables that get created in the local db to support the operation of the sync - so if I delete the sync group would that automatically drop those helper tables as well or would I have to drop those manually - If I do drop those then that will obviously brake the other sync group that works fin as well..

Any advice is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check the Event Log entries on the box where you installed the SQL Data Sync Agent.

Event Viewer->Applications and Services Logs->Sql Azure Data Sync Preview

or Event Viewer->Applications and Services Logs->Data Sync Service

or you may also try turning logging in verbose mode.

Open LocalAgentHost.exe.config in notepad. This file should be present in your installation directory.

a) Uncomment the section that is currently commented
< !-- 
< switches>
< add name="SyncAgentTracer" value="4" />
< /switches>
< trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
< listeners>
< add name="myListener" type="Microsoft.SqlAzureDataSync.ClientLogging.DSSClientTraceListener, Microsoft.SqlAzureDataSync.ClientLogging, Version=2.0.0.0" initializeData="DSSAgentOutput.log" />
< remove name="Default" />
< /listeners>
< /trace>
-->

b) Stop and restart SQL Azure Data Sync Preview Windows Service.
Now you would find the detailed logs in files named DSSAgentOutput*.log.

If you delete the sync group and the tables are part of other sync groups or you have other sync groups, the deprovisioning will not completely remove everything, just that particular sync group definition.

Comment: This log doesn't show me what exactly is happening. The "failure" element is empty and it shows a count of how many rows failed. Just as I can see in the Azure Portal.